# How to Rollback from iPad beta SDK to iPhone SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, rollback

If I update to the iPhone SDK 3.2 beta, will I then be able to rollback to iPhone SDK 3.1.2 (xcode 3.2.1) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can install new SDKs in non-/Developer paths. This is what you should do with any new, NDA-PROTECTED SDKs. Perhaps /Developer-Beta.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ben.  Apologies for my lack of understanding here.  Would you be able to elaborate just a little on how this practice enables / eases the rollback procedure?  Thanks Simon

Comment: It eases it in that you can simply delete the beta directory - just make sure to install into something like /Developer-3.2 instead of /Developer

Comment: See also Michael Jurewitz's image of the key Xcode installation screen where you select this directory: http://emberapp.com/users/jurewitz/images/installer