# iPhone SDK 3.2 beta and iPhone SDK 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, sdk, versions

Currently I am using iPhone SDK 3.1.2 for developing iPhone apps.

Apple has recently released iPhone SDK 3.2 beta and I want to try my hands with it.

But my problem is that I want to use both versions of SDKs, 3.1.2 since I am currently developing apps and uploading on app store, 3.2 beta to start trying the new version (but Apple will not accept apps on App Store, if developed using 3.2 beta)

Please guide me.

Regards,
Pratik

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195669/if-i-have-iphone-sdk-3-2-is-there-any-way-i-can-use-3-1-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still build your old app under 3.1.2 while 3.2 beta is installed.  To do it, simply hold down the option key while clicking the top left dropdown menu in XCode. This will list all of your installed SDK's and you simply choose 3.1.2

Comment: @coneybeare: Thanks, one more thing, I have already downloaded 3.2 beta, and currently 3.1.2 is installed on my machine, do I need to uninstall 3.1.2 and than install 3.2 or simply install 3.2.

Comment: Don't do this!  Install to a different location in the installer until 3.2 is out. It has some bugs and apple does not want you submitting apps built in a beta sdk. 2 copies of the sdk in different places allows you to play around in one and release real apps in the final and current sdk.

Comment: but you might want to install it in a different directory, like /Developer32beta, just in case...

Comment: If I install 3.2 at different location then I will have two versions of SDKs on machine, how my app will know which version it should work with. If app for 3.1.2 should open/work with 3.1.2 and app for 3.2 should open/work with 3.2

Comment: Just keep the base target at 3.1.2, but you can still test in the simulator with 3.2

Comment: You can play with both SDK's even if they are both installed on your machine in the same spot. Squeegy is wrong.  Just build under an older SDK using the method presented.  You also can get both sets of docs.

Comment: I think Squeegy is right...there is same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151159/how-to-rollback-from-ipad-beta-sdk-to-iphone-sdk-3-1
and its saying the same as Squeegy and others are saying.

Comment: Believe what you want.  I can only tell you that I have many different SDK's installed, and always build under 3.0 for all my apps.  I have been doing this since 3.0 came out.  Why complicate your life with different directories when you can just combine it without a problem?

Comment: @coneybeare: plz dnt take it personal...I jst said frm what I read here.